# Javascript/PHP: empty $_POST and $_FILES arrays after FileTransfer() upload

Tags: javascript, php, file, post, upload

So I have a web app running in a webview on a mobile, and I'm trying to upload a picture from the smartphone to my server, using FileTransfer() just like this:

```
var imageURI = 'file:///path/to/picture.jpg';
var params = { foo: 'bar' };
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = 'file';
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = 'text/plain';
    options.headers = { Connection: 'close' };
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.params = params;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI('http://example.com/uploads/upload.php'), win, fail, options);
```

This code works like a charm if I target *upload.php* on a **Plesk** server, the picture is sent in `$_FILES` array, and `$_POST['foo'] = 'bar'`.

I've put the exacte same *upload.php* file on a **Debian** server a friend of mine installed, and when I'm targeting it, both `$_POST` and `$_FILES` are empty arrays! Everything else works fine, no PHP or server errors, just empty arrays.

As suggested in [other topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852910/php-empty-post-and-files-when-uploading-larger-files) I checked `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` and `max_input_time` that are way above what's needed, and I even added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` at the begining of *upload.php*.

Any idea?

Comment: This smells like a php.ini or apache config issue `:|`