# PHP: Fails to catch error for oversize file upload exceeds post_max_size

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to catch error for an oversize file upload.

My limit (MAX_FILE_SIZE in the form & also later for $_FILES['uploadFile']['size']) is 10Mb / 10485760 bytes

In php.ini, I have:

- post_max_size = 30M
- upload_max_filesize = 20M

Everytime I upload between 10M (the limit) and post_max_size (30M), error could be caught, but when it was exceed 30M, **it would go straight to home address** (in my case: http://project.dev/admin/), without any error being logged.

This is my HTML code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="./skrip.php" method="post" name="thisForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760">
<label>Upload file</label>
<input class="upload" type="file" name="uploadFile" class="file" id="uploadFile">
<button>Submit</button
</form>
```

And this is my skrip.php

```
$displayMaxSize = ini_get('post_max_size') * 1024 * 1024;

if (  $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > $displayMaxSize
   || $_FILES['uploadFile']['size'] > 10485760) {
    throw new Exception('PHP discarded POST data because of request exceeding post_max_size.');
}

... continue to file validation
```

I tried accepted answer from this SO posts below but still fails:

[PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of n bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738949/php-warning-post-content-length-of-n-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-3145728-bytes-i?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to gracefully handle files that exceed PHP's `post_max_size`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133652/how-to-gracefully-handle-files-that-exceed-phps-post-max-size)

[PHP - empty $_POST and $_FILES - when uploading larger files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852910/php-empty-post-and-files-when-uploading-larger-files)

Comment: What is your `memory_limit` set to in your php.ini? I also applaud you for actually posting what you tried *and* questions you used to help yourself

Comment: First 128M, now 512MB, but still fails.
Your comment made me remember my experience with memory limit. Is it possible because of it?

Comment: Just to check, What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.1.12 on LinuxMint 18.2